# How to I use FixedPage markup on a Content Model control?

Tags: wpf, xaml, xps, fixedpage

In WPF, I have tried passing the mark-up of an XPS file's FixedPage to a control that has the `Content` property (ex. `Button.Content = XamlReader.Load(<FixedPage markup>)`).

Example of FixedPage markup:

```
<FixedPage Width="816" Height="1056" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xps/2005/06" xml:lang="und">
    <Path Data="M 115.52,132.48 L 704.64,132.48 704.64,908.96 115.52,908.96 z" Clip="M 0,132.32 L 0,908.8 816,908.8 816,132.32 z">
        <Path.Fill>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Documents/1/Resources/Images/1.JPG" Viewbox="0,0,809.333,1066.67" TileMode="None" ViewboxUnits="Absolute" ViewportUnits="Absolute" Viewport="115.52,132.48,589.12,776.48" />
        </Path.Fill>
    </Path>
</FixedPage>
```

The control was not able to get the resource referred to in the FixedPage mark-up.

```
ImageSource="/Documents/1/Resources/Images/1.JPG"
```

But if I change the `ImageSource` to a local path file like *"c:\1.jpg"* and put the resource file in the same location, the control will be able to display the FixedPage mark-up.

My question is, is there a way for the control to display the FixedPage while retaining the relative URI of the resource in order to avoid modifying the FixedPage mark-up? Like mapping the XPS file's structure in memory and then setting the `BaseUri` of the FixedPage markup by the `ParserContext` class during the call to `XamlReader.Load()`? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not.  Even if the ImageBrush can work with the PackageStore, the URI is malformed; its missing the root of the XPS Document in the package store.